# Unit Test with Mock

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to test my API and I use a mock. I have a method to test the good comportment of my API :

```
    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void requestShouldReturnCode200() throws Exception {     
        restMeteoMockMvc.perform(get("/api/myAPI/{param1},{param2}", GOOD_PARAM1, GOOD_PARAM2)
                .accept(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

The signature of the method I want test is :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/myAPI/{param1},{param2}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)    
public ResponseEntity<Object> get(@PathVariable Float param1, @PathVariable Float param2)
```

I think I made a mistake in the way to send parameters of the method to test... Isn't it ?
Because in my redirect file for the results of the test, I can see that requestShouldReturnCode200 received a 400 code and expected 200.

```
requestShouldReturnCode200(com.bookstore.web.rest.MyClassResourceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.032 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:653)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:152)
    at com.bookstore.web.rest. com.bookstore.web.rest.MyClassResourceTest.requestShouldReturnCode200(com.bookstore.web.rest.MyClassResourceTest.java:60)
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Why do you think you made a mistake? What outcome are you expecting, and what did you actually get? Also, are you using a mocking framework like Mockito or PowerMock?

Comment: I edit to post my errors, and yes I use Mockito

Comment: What are the RequestMapping annotations on the method and on the controller class? We can't guess the URL from a method signature.

Comment: It's important also to know what actual values have you sent as method arguments (GOOD_PARAM1, GOOD_PARAM2). Are these floats?

Comment: Topic updated, thank's. So yes, GOOD_PARAM1/2 are Floats :(